# JSF multiple @ViewScoped and @ManagedBeans on same page results in null injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jsf-2

I have two classes as follows:

```
@ManagedBean( name = "randomBar")  
@ViewScoped  
public class Soap  
{  
   private List<Cat> cats;  
   //getter/setter pair  
}  


@ManagedBean ( name = "marioPaint")  
@ViewScoped  
public class House  
{  
   @ManagedProperty(value= "#{randomBar}")  
   private Soap soap  
   //getter/setter pair
...

public void printCatInformation()
{
   System.out.println(soap.getCats()); //null  
 }
```

These are both on the same page.  The `Soap` object is able to print to console it's size while `House` is unable to get anything beyond a null pointer.  My question is how do I send that information back to the instance of `Soap` that is present inside of `House`?

Update:
This is running on Oracle 10.3.4 with Icefaces 2.0 (Mojarra).

Comment: Where is `System.out.println(soap.getCats());`?

Comment: inside a method that happens to print out the size of my cat list that is invoked from a page.

Comment: Can you try changing your `Soap` to `@SessionScoped`, if haven't done it?

Comment: SessionScope is not going to be functionally appropriate for this page.

Comment: The symptoms suggests that they do not refer the **same** instance. Debug `#{soap.hashCode()}` and `#{house.soap.hashCode()}`. If they're different, then that explains it. Before posting an answer, I'd like to know the concrete functional requirement for this. I am namely wondering why `Soap` needs to be another managed bean.

Comment: @BalusC  It happens to be that the page is currently being built using the ui:include to have multiple pages, that I guess technically stand on their own.  The one is a "footer" that is passed along multiple pages.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `ui:include` has got nothing to do with why you have two backing beans.It is one rendered page i.e. one view should have one viewscoped bean. Having two view scoped bean at the same time is just plain wrong in my opinion . But since @BalusC has not objected that I might be wrong but smells to me.You could use `marioPaint.soap.property`.No need for Soap to be viewscoped or accessed directly. Post your Xhtml page(s) as well , which server are you using and which implementaion of JSf2 i.e Myfaces or Mojarra .

Comment: @Shahzeb I have updated the configuration information, I will post up the page tomorrow.